# Return to parent component if error received from post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that makes a call to an external service onClick.

When the onClick happens, it sets the showPlaceholder component to true, which shows a placeholder whilst the external request is happening. If the request is successful the user is directed to their dashboard. If the request is unsuccessful, I want the placeholder component to not show and the parent component to render the error message.

Everything is working as expected but I can’t remove the placeholder when an error is raised. Any advice?

```
    const ParentComponent = () => {

    const [idNumber, setidNumber] = useState("");
    const [showPlaceholder, setShowPlaceholder] = useState(false);

    const OnClickHandler = () => {
        setShowPlaceholder(true);
        we post the data here and start the request
        
    };

    return (
        <>
            {showPlaceholder ? <showPlaceholder error={error} /> :
                <>
                    <input
                        value={idNumber}
                        onChange={idNumber => setidNumber((idNumber))} />
                    <button
                        onClick={OnClickHandler}
                    >
                        Continue
                    </button>

                    {error && <p>errorMessage</p>}
                </>
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

Child Component

```
const Placeholder = (error) => {
    if (error === true) {
        cancelOnClickHandler();
    }

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        STOP SHOWING THE PLACEHOLDER
        
    };

    return (
        <div >
            <div>
                Loader...
            </div>
            <Link
                onClick={onClickHandler}
            >
                cancel
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Placeholder;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code:

1. All react components' names should we written using `PascalCase`:

```
{showPlaceholder ? <ShowPlaceholder error={error} /> // <ShowPlaceholder /> instead of <showPlaceholder />
```

2. Below you pass `error` variable as a `prop` to `ShowPlaceholder`, but no such variable exists in your code

```
{showPlaceholder ? <ShowPlaceholder error={error} /> // no error varaible exists in your scope
```

3. You are not destructuring your `prop` inside of `ShowPlaceholder` component

```
// either            v here v
const Placeholder = ({ error }) => {
    if (error === true) {
        ... your code
// or
const Placeholder = (props) => {
    // v here v
    if (props.error === true) {
        ... your code
```

To remove your `ShowPlaceholder` when `error` is raised, you need to set your `showPlaceholder` variable to `false` using `setShowPlaceholder` when your external service returns error response, but you didn't supply code for it so I can't help you.
But if you want to close `ShowPlaceholder` with your button, do this:

```
// in Parent component, add this prop:
<ShowPlaceholder error={error} hidePlaceholder={() => setShowPlaceholder(false)} />

const Placeholder = (props) => {
    // ... code ...

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        props.hidePlaceholder()
    };

    // ... code ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Event though I didn't get where your error state is controlled, What you need to do is to control  your child components visibility in Parent component. Use async function and try catch blog to make api post. However, there are some other problems with your code to be solved.

```js
const [error, setError] = useState(""); // Add error state to your Parent Component.

const OnClickHandler = async () => {

       setShowPlaceholder(true);
       try {
          const res = axios.post(blah blah blah);
          setData(res.data) // or whatever you want to do with the data.

       }catch(err) {
          setShowPlaceHolder(false);
          setError(err);
       }

   };
```